# why it is giving error when I run npm install?

Tags: reactjs

while running `npm install` getting below error:

> package.json file is present but still it is giving error

[image]

Comment: Try installing again after deleting the package-lock.json file and the node modules folder.

Comment: Also, post your `package.json` file contents.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you installed the current version of react, but the other package (react-particles) is not the current version, as it depends on an older version of react. These two conflicting versions of react are incompatible, so you should probably delete your node_modules and update all your packages to the current version.